# My document is not getting deleted in mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My document is not getting deleted from the collections. Iam also not getting any error. The http transaction is perfectly fine.

```
// Node Module dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Local Module dependencies
var common = require('./common.js');
//var request = require('request');


var db =common.conn;
var Question = require('../model/questions');


router.route('/postquestion')
    .post(function (req, res) {

        var item = new Question(req.body);
        //console.log(item);

        //=======calling postdata method=====//
        postQuestion(item, function (result) {

            res.json(result);
        });

    });

router.route('/deletequestion')
    .delete(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body._id);

    Question.collection.deleteOne({_id:req.body._id},function(err,question){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('the document is deleted')
        res.send(question);

    });

})
function postQuestion(item, fn) {
    item.save(function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        fn(item);
    });
}
module.exports = router;
```

postquestion function is working perfectly fine and the database is getting updated. When i use postman for raising a delete request and send the below json.

```
{
    "_id": "57bc442c4925180b067f075b"
}
```

iam getting a response like the below.

```
   {
   "ok": 1,
   "n": 0
   }
```

When i check the database in robomongo i see the document is not deleted. Am i missing something to be done. Is there anything else to be done.....!

Comment: `console.log(req.body._id);` ? if `undefined`, then use `body-parser`

Comment: no req.body._id is not undefined it is logged with a value of the id without quotes....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB uses ObjectID to index document.

If you want to delete object using Mongo ID you have to instanciate an ObjectID.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.deleteOne/

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
router.route('/deletequestion')
    .delete(function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body._id);
    const _id = new ObjectID(req.body._id);
    Question.collection.deleteOne({_id:_id},function(err,question){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('the document is deleted')
        res.send(question);

    });

})
```

Comment: any pointers on how to do that... i tried sending the input as "_id": ObjectId("57bc442c4925180b067f075b") but it is not taking it {
  "message": "Unexpected token O",
  "error": {
    "body": "{\n    \"_id\": ObjectId(\"57bc442c4925180b067f075b\")\n}",
    "status": 400,
    "statusCode": 400
  }
}

Comment: it worked.... thank you thanks a lot... So in node everything highly depends on the format or prototype of the object.....sending the data in right format also matters a lot... so how can i learn to know what form of data is needed in that place....

Answer (score 1):

if nothing works, try the following...

```
   app.delete("/api/posts/:id",(req,res,next)=> 
{  
   Post.deleteOne({_id: req.param.id})
   .then(result=>{
     console.log(result);
   });
   //console.log('Post Deleted on node JS');
   res.status(200).json({message: 'Delete'}); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongooseJS, you just need to do `Question.deleteOne({...}), you don't need to do the`Question.collection...` thing.  Unless you have stuff wired up differently in your Model

Comment: i tried it  but it is saying that Question.deleteOne is not a function....! but my version runs without error...

Comment: here is how i wired up the model with mongoose......the conn contains the connection in this way conn: require('mongoose').createConnection(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||  'mongodb://localhost:27017/medicoshere')     var Question = common.conn.model('Question', questionSchema);
module.exports = Question;

Comment: I think if you just do a `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` then you can setup your connection with `mongoose.connect(<url>);` and you can create your model with `mongoose.model()`.  Then the export will have access to the full set of Mongoose functions (including deleteOne) and you shouldn't have to do anything extra with the ObjectID, just pass in a string of the ID.

Comment: I guess this is also very dependant on what version of MongooseJS you are using.

Comment: Just to give an example, this is how they demo a really basic setup on the MongooseJS site:

`var mongoose = require('mongoose');`
`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');`
`var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });`
`var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });`
`kitty.save(function (err) {`
`if (err) {`
`        console.log(err);`
`    } else {`
`        console.log('meow');`
`    }`
`});`